# "Component" does not contain a definition for "enabled"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to disable PlayerControllerScript by:

```
this.GetComponent("PlayerControllerScript").enabled = false;
```

But there is an error in title.
What should I do?

Comment: [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) returns a `Component` which does not have an `enabled` property. Read through the linked documentation for examples on how to convert that to an object of a specific type. Since `GetComponent` is slow, and the string version is the worst, you'll likely want to cache the result in a variable and then modify it rather than use `GetComponent` every time you want to access it.

Comment: yes, but what should I do? what should I change in my code exactly?

Comment: @RetiredNinja since they switched to a hash based `GetComponent` it is actually not that slow anymore ;) of course caching still makes sense in cases where you need it multiple times ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) has multiple overloads:

- `public Component GetComponent(Type type);`
- `public Component GetComponent(string type);`
- `public T GetComponent<T>();`

[`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) indeed doesn't have `enabled`. Only [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) (and subclasses) does since

> Behaviours are Components that can be enabled or disabled.

Rather use the generic overload

```
GetComponent<PlayerControllerScript>().enabled = false;
```

which rather returns a `PlayerControllerScript` which most probably is a `MonoBehaviour` which then inherits [`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)

alternatively you could also cast - but why go that way?

```
((PlayerControllerScript)GetComponent("PlayerControllerScript")).enabled = false;
```

---

As was mentioned in general it makes sense to cache references and if possible even avoid `GetComponent` completely like e.g.

```
// Already reference via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private PlayerControllerScript playerController;

private void Awake ()
{
    // or get ONCE as fallback
    if(! playerController) playerController = GetComponent<PlayerControllerScript>();

    playerController.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetComponent(string type)` is deprecated, which means that using it is not recommended, and you should look for another overload of the method.

One of the best way to do this is by using the method `GetComponent<Type>()`, where you directly put the type of your script in the place of `Type` instead of searching it through a string.

You should also consider to call only once `GetComponent()`, for example in the `Start()` method of your MonoBehaviour class, and save a reference to the script in a variable to avoid calling `GetComponent()` each time you need to do something with it, for performance reasons.

Something like that:

```
private PlayerControllerScript playerController;

private void Start()
{
    playerController = this.GetComponent<PlayerControllerScript>();

    playerController.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: It is absolutely [**not** deprecated](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) and there are valid use cases where it needs to be dynamic via strings or types ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I re-checked and the method is not officially deprecated, however its use is not recommended since there're better solutions than getting a script via its string name